# Laravel routes/controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a clean guy when I code and I don't like typing the same thing over and over again, so I will try to be simple.

In my Laravel project I have two routes for every major page on the website, for example:

```
Route::get('/artigos','GlobalController@gestorArtigos');
Route::get('/artigos/{id}','GlobalController@gestorArtigos');
```

When it receives an ID in the controller:

```
 public function gestorArtigos(Request $request , $id = '') {
    $MyOutput = view('artigos.art_gestor_base');
    if($id){
        return $MyOutput->with('id',$id);
    }
    return $MyOutput->with('request',$request);
}
```

This is completely fine and I have no intention of changing this. What does bother me is the fact that I have to repeat the same function every single time I create a new page. The only differences are the function name and the value of `$MyOutput`, because the views change.

I need help to compact the function to a 'global' one so I don't have to repeat the code, just call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to pass `$request` to the view, because you can access it anyway with Laravel's helper `request()` function.

For the routes you can use [optional parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#parameters-optional-parameters), something like.

```
Route::get('/artigos/{id?}','GlobalController@gestorArtigos');
```

For the views and repetitive checks you can always use [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers) or [middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware) depends on the case really.

Eventually you could create `trait` with function to perform this repetitive task and include it in controller, for instance:

```
trait RepetitiveTask
{
    public function fireView($output, $id)
    {
        return ($id) ? $output->with('id', $id) : $output;
    } 
}

class YourController 
{
    use RepetitiveTask;

    public function gestorArtigos(Request $request) 
    {
        return $this->fireView(view('artigos.art_gestor_base'), $request->id);
    }
}
```

However i would use **middlewares** or **view composers** instead.

Whatever you do, make sure you keep the logic out of the views.

Comment: Wow, works like a charm, thank you very much, so compact now!